# How do I detect an ember application at runtime

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to find a better way of detecting an  ember application than searching for `ember-application` or `window.ember`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "detecting an Ember application". What do you want to detect? That Ember exists? That an Ember application has been created? That one is running? Remember, you can use Ember without creating an `Application` instance, and you can also run multiple `Application` instances on the same page.

Comment: either that ember exists or that an ember app is running. @GJK

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no guaranteed way to detect Ember or an Ember Application. Javascript is fairly malleable, so you could have either on a page and not know where.

To detect Ember, just check for `window.Ember`. Nothing fancy here, it's pretty much the only way to know (until Ember is no longer global that is). I would say this works in *most* scenarios (both Ember global and Ember CLI apps).

Detecting an Ember application is much more difficult. The last time I checked, the Ember Inspector does this by checking every property on the `window` object using `Ember.Application.detectInstance()`. However, given the gaining popularity of Ember CLI, that will no longer work much of the time. *Maybe* you could override `Ember.Application.create()` and keep track of the instances?

In any case, I certainly wouldn't rely on being able to do either of these. It's simply not feasible.